# I have used header in list view and getting this error as defined below

Tags: android

The whole concept I am using is when i clicked a textview inside a single list item of list view, i called a method defined in the activity from my adapter class and then in that method , i have hit an api and when i get the response , I again load the list and the i got this error.

My adapter class..

```
public class NewsFeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<NewsFeed> newsFeedArrayList;
String residentId;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
//NewsFeedActivity newsFeedActivity;

public NewsFeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsFeed> newsFeedArrayList,String residentId) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsFeedArrayList = newsFeedArrayList;
    this.residentId = residentId;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView friendProfilePic,feedImage,deletePostBtn,likeBtn,commentBtn;
    TextView friendName,postTime,feedPostTxt,totalLikes,totalComments;
    RelativeLayout likeBtnLayout,commentBtnLayout,feedPostImageLayout;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return newsFeedArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return newsFeedArrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_feed_list_item,viewGroup,false);
        viewHolder.friendProfilePic = view.findViewById(R.id.friend_profile_pic);
        viewHolder.friendName = view.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);
        viewHolder.postTime = view.findViewById(R.id.feed_post_date);
        viewHolder.feedImage = view.findViewById(R.id.feed_post_image);
        viewHolder.feedPostTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.feed_post_text);
        viewHolder.deletePostBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_post_btn);
        viewHolder.likeBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.like_btn);
        viewHolder.commentBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);
        viewHolder.totalLikes = view.findViewById(R.id.no_of_likes);
        viewHolder.totalComments = view.findViewById(R.id.no_of_comments);
        viewHolder.likeBtnLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.like_btn_layout);
        viewHolder.commentBtnLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn_layout);
        viewHolder.feedPostImageLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.feed_post_image_layout);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    //Log.w(AppConfig.TAG,"position is "+i);

    final NewsFeed newsFeed = newsFeedArrayList.get(i);
    viewHolder.feedImage.setBottom(0);
    Glide.with(context).load(newsFeed.getFriendprofilePic())
            .asBitmap().centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(viewHolder.friendProfilePic) {
        @Override
        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            viewHolder.friendProfilePic.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.friendName.setText(newsFeed.getFriendName());
    viewHolder.postTime.setText(newsFeed.getPostTime());

    //Log.w(AppConfig.TAG,"pos is "+i+newsFeed.getFeedImage()+"");
    if (!newsFeed.getFeedImage().equals("null")){
        viewHolder.feedPostImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(context).load(newsFeed.getFeedImage())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(viewHolder.feedImage);

    }
    else {
        viewHolder.feedPostImageLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    viewHolder.feedPostTxt.setText(newsFeed.getFeedPostTxt());
    if (newsFeed.getFriendId().equals(residentId)){
        viewHolder.deletePostBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.deletePostBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (Integer.parseInt(newsFeed.getTotalLikes())>0){
        viewHolder.totalLikes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.totalLikes.setText(newsFeed.getTotalLikes()+" Likes");
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.totalLikes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (Integer.parseInt(newsFeed.getTotalComments())>0){
        viewHolder.totalComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.totalComments.setText(newsFeed.getTotalComments()+" Comments");
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.totalComments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    viewHolder.totalLikes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LikesResidentNamesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppConfig.POST_ID,newsFeed.getPostId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.totalComments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AllCommentsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppConfig.POST_ID,newsFeed.getPostId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.likeBtnLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NewsFeedActivity newsFeedActivity = (NewsFeedActivity) context;
            newsFeedActivity.likeDislikePost(newsFeed.getPostId());
        }
    });

    viewHolder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addComment(newsFeed);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.commentBtnLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addComment(newsFeed);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.deletePostBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deletePost(newsFeed.getPostId());

        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void deletePost(final String postId){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Delete Confirm?");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to delete this post?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            NewsFeedActivity newsFeedActivity = (NewsFeedActivity) context;
            newsFeedActivity.deletePost(postId);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void addComment(NewsFeed newsFeed){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AllCommentsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppConfig.POST_ID,newsFeed.getPostId());
    context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and this is my activity code..

```
public class NewsFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView toolbarTitle;
ImageView backBtn;
ListView newsFeedListView;
ArrayList<NewsFeed> newsFeedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
NewsFeedAdapter newsFeedAdapter;
HashMap<String,String> residentDetails;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);
    toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    backBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    toolbarTitle.setText("News Feed");
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AppConfig.goBackToParentActivity(NewsFeedActivity.this);
        }
    });


    DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(NewsFeedActivity.this);
    residentDetails = databaseManager.getResidentDetails();

    newsFeedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.news_feed_list_view);
    View newsFeedListViewHeader = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.news_feed_list_header,null);
    newsFeedListView.addHeaderView(newsFeedListViewHeader);

    newsFeedAdapter = new NewsFeedAdapter(this,newsFeedArrayList,residentDetails.get(AppConfig.RESIDENT_ID));
    newsFeedListView.setAdapter(newsFeedAdapter);


    loadNewsFeed();
}

private void loadNewsFeed(){
    newsFeedArrayList.clear();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,AppConfig.NEWS_FEED_METHOD, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.w(AppConfig.TAG,response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getInt(AppConfig.STATUS_CODE) == 201){
                    JSONArray newsFeedArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConfig.RESPONSE);
                    if (newsFeedArray.length()>0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < newsFeedArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject newsFeedObject = newsFeedArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            newsFeedArrayList.add(new NewsFeed(newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.POST_ID), newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.RESIDENT_ID), newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.RESIDENT_NAME), newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.RESIDENT_IMAGE),
                                    AppConfig.strToDate(newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.POST_DATE)), newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.POST_IMG), newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.POST_STATUS),
                                    newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.TOTAL_LIKES), newsFeedObject.getString(AppConfig.TOTAL_COMMENTS)));

                        }
                        newsFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(AppConfig.RESIDENT_SOCIETY_ID,residentDetails.get(AppConfig.RESIDENT_SOCIETY_ID));
            params.put(AppConfig.RESIDENT_ID,residentDetails.get(AppConfig.RESIDENT_ID));
            Log.w(AppConfig.TAG,params+"");
            return params;
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == AppConfig.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE){
        newsFeedArrayList.clear();
        loadNewsFeed();
    }
}



public void deletePost(String postId){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, AppConfig.DELETE_POST_METHOD+postId, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.w(AppConfig.TAG,response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getInt(AppConfig.STATUS_CODE)==201){
                    Toast.makeText(NewsFeedActivity.this, "Your post has been deleted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    newsFeedArrayList.clear();
                    loadNewsFeed();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(NewsFeedActivity.this, "Some error occured!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}


public void likeDislikePost(final String postId){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.LIKE_UNLIKE_POST_METHOD, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.w(AppConfig.TAG,response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getInt(AppConfig.STATUS_CODE) == 201){

                    loadNewsFeed();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(AppConfig.RESIDENT_SOCIETY_ID,residentDetails.get(AppConfig.RESIDENT_SOCIETY_ID));
            params.put(AppConfig.RESIDENT_ID,residentDetails.get(AppConfig.RESIDENT_ID));
            params.put(AppConfig.POST_ID,postId);
            Log.w(AppConfig.TAG,params+"");
            return params;
        }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
 }
```

Logcat

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>                                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3467)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17337)
>                                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4704)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16264)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3874)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3854)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16218)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3874)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3854)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16218)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3874)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3854)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16218)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3874)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3854)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16218)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3874)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3854)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16218)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3874)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3854)
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16218)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:661)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:667)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:775)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3188)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2981)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2569)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
>                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6965)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
>                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Comment: post your code..

Comment: post your response too.

Comment: i have posted now, Please check and help me

Comment: viewHolder.likeBtnLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NewsFeedActivity newsFeedActivity = (NewsFeedActivity) context;
            newsFeedActivity.likeDislikePost(newsFeed.getPostId());
        }
    });    .. this is the code where i hit the method of activity.. i have defined above

Comment: I'm not sure if this can cause that particular Exception, but you never want to change the `Adapter`'s dataset without calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. That can happen in `loadNewsFeed()`, since you're clearing the list first thing, but then only conditionally calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Move the `clear()` call to right before the `for` loop that repopulates the list. If that doesn't fix it, debug to check the results count, and that no Exception is being thrown inside that `try`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it worked like a charm, but can you please explain me, because i first clear the list and then add the new list and then i called adapter.notifychanged, then why is this happen, and also in my all other listviews, i have used the same concept, and it is working

Comment: Your `StringRequest` isn't going to return immediately, so there's going to be some amount of time between you calling `clear()`, and then finally calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Apparently, during that time, something is triggering a redraw or refresh on the `ListView`, but it wasn't yet notified that the list contents had been changed (cleared, actually), so it ends up trying to get information from the `Adapter` with invalid data. Follow me?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got you. Hey i am unable to follow you, there is no follow link showing in your profile

Comment: There isn't really any kind of a "follow user" functionality on Stack Overflow. They want to keep this a pretty straightforward question-and-answer site, rather than a social networking kinda thing. I'm usually around here in the [android] tag most every day, though. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot for your response..